# Getting the id of the current android system theme?

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes, alert

I have an application in which I need to set the alert dialog's style to the one currently used by system dialogs. The application has a predifined theme set which is different from the system one. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: alertDialog theming is very buggy. Which version are you targeting?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Im targeting API 14 and up

Comment: i have been trying to theme alert dialogs, in version 2.3 and below, it does not really work. In the AlertDialog.Builder, there is a param which is the theme to use. Use one from android.R.style. Theme_DeviceDefault could be the one you need.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, Theme_DeviceDefault does not necessarly have to be the current theme used by the system.